# How to install a Brother MFC-5890CN network printer?

Tags: printing, brother

How to install Network Printer (**Brother MFC-5890CN**) in Ubuntu 11.10.

Anybody can help me to install this printer in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Brother](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html) have a fantastic compatibility linux drivers:

you have three ways to install a printer :

1. **Local Printer**

in the principal page you can see a how to :

Instruction

Printer (CUPS) :   [Driver Install](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1.html)  |  [Print Command](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn2.html)  |  [More Information](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn5.html)  |

Printer (LPR) :    [Driver Install](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html)  |  [Print Command](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn4.html)  |  [More Information](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn6.html)  |

go to this page :

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-5890CN

download LPR and cupswrapper driver all available in .DEB format and install it, follow the brother instruction..

1. **Setup a Standalone Network Printer or
   Setup a Shared Windows Printer**

Follow this [guide](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/10/first-30-days-with-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelotday-four/)

Comment: Thank you hhlp. I already install the Network printer in Ubuntu 11.10 I follow the Instruction in Brothersoft. I also installed the Scanner driver but I can't run the scanner driver automatically. When the time I use printer I use the command in Terminal "sudo brscan-skey" to scan. I already setup the auto start application using that command but when the pc restart it has no effect I manually use that command in Terminal in order to work the scanner in brothersoft.